# How to parse a json in which the object sometime acts as a string or an array in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I did in Volley but I wanted to do in Retrofit. I also Searched in stack overflow but the solutions were a bit confusing. The following is the json.

```
[{
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "value": "49"
    },
    {
        "attribute_code": "category_ids",
        "value": [
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "attribute_code": "options_container",
        "value": "container2"
    }]
```

The following is the POJO class.

```
public class ModelCustomAttrRes {
@SerializedName("attribute_code")
@Expose
private String attributeCode;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private String value;

public String getAttributeCode() {
    return attributeCode;
}

public void setAttributeCode(String attributeCode) {
    this.attributeCode = attributeCode;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

Comment: You should not use such schema, change the back end to get the values as array of string even if there is only one.

Comment: post your code, show us what you tried so far

Comment: Nabin Bhandari i cant change backend bcoz its based on magento.

Comment: @akhilesh0707 icould tell you the error which i got while parsing in retrofit ###Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 1403 path###

Comment: you are getting this error because `value` field inside your json

Comment: which is array in your second element and string in your first and last element, you need to change from server side

Comment: Nabin Bhnadari has a point. You can not use such schema. Your all objects should be same. Though you are getting single value in response as a string, you have to use array their so all objects will be same. And retrofit  easily parse your response. You need to change your server side implementation.

Comment: @PallaviTapkir i completely understand what you are trying to say but backend is completely based on Magento Where we cannot minipulate the Json as i know .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your String value in **Object**, Your POJO would be like this.I'm sure it will work for you. Object data type does hold string and array both value.

```
public class ModelCustomAttrRes {
@SerializedName("attribute_code")
@Expose
private String attributeCode;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private Object value;

public String getAttributeCode() {
return attributeCode;
}

public void setAttributeCode(String attributeCode) {
this.attributeCode = attributeCode;
}

public Object getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(Object value) {
this.value = value;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ramesh for identifying the problem. It worked What i expected .